# Resize image on html

Tags: html, css

I am doing my first website and I have some trouble with image fittings.

I got a template for a slidershow on internet but I would like to add a vertical image to it with the following code:

```
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-fullwidth" style="width=3100px">
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte5.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte6.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/Raco/projecte7.jpg" class="horit">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The classes owl-carousel are given to me in the template. So to fit the horizontal image (projecte7) I created the class "horit" with this CSS:

```
.horit{
    max-height:500px;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone explain me why? Thank you so much.
You can look at the web at http://gmarquitectes.cat/terrassa2005.html to see the problem

I have it like this now:

[See that this vertical image goes way too down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S5TN.jpg)

And I would like vertical images to fit in with the rest like this:

[Here if the image has another size it appears smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lulZB.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure to have understood... I understood that you want to put an image "inside" another image, is it right? If so, you have at least to put the `z-index: 10` property to show the little image above the larger one

Comment: Hi! What I would like to do is adjust a vertical image to the same height as all the other horitzontal images so that all the other aspects (like the black arrows if you click the link) fit well.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Copy & paste screenshot of the desired result and your current state in the post.

Comment: Ok. Now I have it like this:

Comment: Hello! well so i think i understood what your Problem is: All The pictures are the Same  size except the one that you want to add and you dont know how you can resize it so it fits in the same area right?

Comment: Yes exactly!! excuse my bad explaining

Comment: Try using `background-image` instead of `img` as it will be more easily to control the size

Comment: I just tried but now it doesn't even show the image (I only changed <img src> o <background-image source>)

Comment: not a problem: In General: You should never make small pictures bigger with code, cause they usually get blurry and stretched. If you change your max-height to 740.14px it will fit in the container. You can use a inspector tool to find the right height: In Chrome for Example you can press F12 to open the developer-console, i checked the Size of the other Pictures and its 1110px width and 740.14px height.

Comment: But if I change the parameter max-height nothing changes (now I have it at 740.14px you told me)

Comment: Oh Sorry, replace it with height: 740.14px not max-height, cause max-height just defines how far it can stretch, as the picture seems to be smaller it wont have any effect cause it just chooses the default size

Comment: and also reload the page with CTRL+F5 so the cache gets cleared  after you changed something

Comment: Hi Anna, use `object-fit: contain;` this solve your problem ;) 
For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Wow that CTRL+F5 thing had me struggling a lot this last days. Thank you

Comment: But now the image looks distortionated instead of reduced

Comment: Ok now with object fit it works. Thanks a lot to everyone really.

Comment: I highly recommend to go through a tutorial like this: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Thanks! I look into it